# How to fix the "Table 'database.teches' doesn't exist" error?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Not sure why migrate is looking for 'teches' rather than the real table name 'techs'??

File: TechsTableSeeder.php

```
class TechsTableSeeder extends Seeder {

/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    Eloquent::unguard();

    Tech::create(
        [
        'name'=>'technology',
        'description'=>'...',
        'year'=>'2014'
        ]);

}

}
```

Upon php artisan db:seed --class="TechsTableSeeder", I get the following error in Terminal:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'database.teches' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `teches` (`name`,
> `description`, `year`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (technology,
> ..., 2014, 2013-12-30 03:23:39, 2013-12-30 03:23:39))

Model Tech.php does exist and was auto-generated through `php artisan generate:model`

`Tech` as follows:

```
class Tech extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It tries to put the table name in the plural.

Just add

```
protected $table = 'tech';
```

In your model class Tech

Comment: I find this to be more than mildly annoying. It is considered bad practice to name databases and tables in the plural, and Laravel promotes and implements this behind the scenes? So far I love Laravel but this feature is annoying

Answer (score 0):

Antonio is right, by the way if it works with the model itself you could instead format your seeder in this way:

```
class TechsTableSeeder extends Seeder {

  public function run()
  {
    $techs = [

    ];

    DB::table('techs')->insert($techs);
  }

}
```

I always prefer this method when I seed.